# How to populate document nested in array of objects in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I want to populate the ingredientsList. 
Is it possible to get the array back with populated ingredients field ? 
How I can do it, if I want just one object out of ingredientsList with populated ingredient ?

Hope you can help :)

My Schema looks like this:

```
export const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Enter a name',
  },
  ingredientsList: [
    {
      ingredient: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Ingredient',
      },
      value: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

My Ingredient Model looks like this:

```
export const IngredientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Enter a name',
  },

  created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the field, `ingredientsList`, is an array of referenced documents from the `Ingredient` collection - you can use `model.populate()` as follows:

```
const recipes = await Recipe.find().populate('ingredientsList');

res.send({ data: orders });
```

This will return all `Recipes` and also expand or populate the `ingredientsList` for each.

Let's say that you only wanted populate the `name` field of each document in `ingredientsList` - you do so as follow:

```
const recipes = await Recipe.find().populate('ingredientsList', 'name');

res.send({ data: orders });
```

This will return all `Recipes` but only populate the `name` field on `ingredientsList` for each.

[Mongoose docs on population](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#population)